# run python cgi from web with local packages installed by anaconda

Tags: python, cgi, virtualenv, anaconda

I have a python cgi file on server and it imports some packages that installed only locally by anaconda(because I've no root privilege on the server). The problem is when I call the file from web, it can not be executed because of those "missing" packages. How can I get through this if I can't have root privilege?

Answer (score 0):

If you can control the environment in which your server runs you can set PYTHONPATH to the path of some directory you have permissions to write in, and then install your third-party modules in that directory.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've solved this problem in a similar way basically. I found that when I call the script from web, it is run by a different user(actually a root user) so that the python called is under usr/bin/, so I inserted the anaconda site-package path into sys.path and it worked.